# Excluding records where subquery returns results that need to be mutually exclusive

Tags: mysql

The title is not really explanatory enough...

I'm running a query hourly to prepare MEMORY tables that are then used for some high intensive traffic for the next hour. Right now the query looks like:

```
INSERT INTO tmp_table
            SELECT DISTINCT SQL_NO_CACHE
            B.*, G.node
            FROM books B
            RIGHT JOIN book_genres G on G.asin=B.asin
            WHERE EXISTS
            (
              SELECT 1 FROM genres K WHERE K.node=G.node
            )
            AND...[nothing special here]
```

So the books table just holds book data with a PRIMARY KEY for asin. book_genres contains asin and node fields and contains lots of nodes that are used in various parts of the site. However the tmp_table only needs to include a sub-set of nodes that are in the genres table, hence the sub-query. Hopefully this is enough without posting the full schema.

We now want to make certain genres mutually exclusive. This would mean doing this after building tmp_table:

```
# Delete records that should have been excluded
DELETE T FROM tmp_table T INNER JOIN 
(
    SELECT N.* FROM tmp_table N INNER JOIN
    (
        SELECT DISTINCT ASIN FROM tmp_table 
        INNER JOIN genres ON genres.node=tmp_table.node
        WHERE isFiction=1
    ) F 
    ON F.asin=N.asin 
    INNER JOIN genres ON  genres.node=N.node
    WHERE genres.isNonFiction=1 
) D 
USING (asin, node)
WHERE D.asin=T.asin AND D.node=T.node
```

So if the asin is in a genre with isFiction=1, all genres with nonFiction=1 are removed.

But this feels ugly: to add data using a query and then remove it again. Is there any way this can be combined into one query to avoid the double-pass. Or am I just making work for myself, given that (after some tweaks and edits) the above does work acceptably quickly.

Any ideas would be appreciated, thanks.

Added example:

```
books table:
asin        title       price     etc...
B111111111  Book1       $0.99     ....
B222222222  Book2       $0.99     ....
B333333333  Book2       $0.99     ....

book_genres table:
asin        node
B111111111  1111
B111111111  2222
B111111111  3333
B111111111  5555
B222222222  1111
B222222222  3333
B222222222  4444
B333333333  1111
B333333333  2222

genres table:
node    name         isFiction    isNonFiction
1111    Bestsellers  0            0
2222    Romance      1            0
3333    Biographies  0            1
4444    History      0            1
```

So after the INSERT INTO has been run, tmp_table will look like this:

```
asin       title       node 
B11111111  Book1       1111
B11111111  Book1       2222
B11111111  Book1       3333
B22222222  Book2       1111
B22222222  Book2       3333
B22222222  Book2       4444
B33333333  Book3       1111
B33333333  Book3       2222
```

Book1 does not have a record for node 5555 because it is not in the genres table and we don't need this in tmp_table. Everything else is pretty much a de-normalisation of data because WHERE identifies a subsection of thousands of books out of millions in the DB, which is much quicker to work with.

The next step ensures that if a book has an isFiction node, all isNonFiction nodes for that book are deleted.

After the DELETE has been run, the end result in tmp_table is:

```
asin       title       node 
B11111111  Book1       1111
B11111111  Book1       2222
B22222222  Book2       1111
B22222222  Book2       3333
B22222222  Book2       4444
B33333333  Book3       1111
B33333333  Book3       2222
```

The only difference being node 3333 has been removed for Book1 because Book1 is in 2222 node which has isFiction=1 and node 3333 has isNonFiction=1. Book2 is unchanged because it does not contain isFiction nodes. Similarly, Book3 is unchanged because it does not contain isNonFiction nodes.

At this stage, it is working with this implementation, although the time to run has doubled from about 20-odd seconds, to about 40. No surprise really as the DELETE is a bit convoluted. It might be a decent enough solution, but I'll be happy if someone else has an idea that would make the whole thing more simple or quicker.

Mark...

Comment: I'm not sure I follow: so Here's what I think you're trying to do:  All books meeting your criteria need to be placed in this temp table.  But any books in the temp table existing in multiple genre's need to have the multiple listings removed Keeping just 1 genre's (boolean value) fiction over nonfiction.  right?

Comment: Some sample data would help here with structure of current tables.

Comment: @xQbert - Example data added. I've clarified above, but we're not just keeping 1 fiction over non-fiction. We delete all non-fiction nodes if the book is in any fiction node, and keep all of the fiction nodes and any nodes where isFiction=0 and isNonFiction=0.

Comment: are the generes bestseller's isFiction and isNonFiction values correct? it seems to be one of the two would always be true.

Comment: @xQbert - these flags indicate where the genre has an exclusive Fiction or NonFiction status. Bestsellers can be both.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

And it was ugly. It works fine until there is any other significant load on the DB, and then it all goes very slowly. This is mostly down to IO limitations of the server, but the simpler approach was to get isfiction and isNonFiction into the MEMORY tables and the DELETE statement can then look like:

```
    DELETE tmp_table FROM tmp_table
         INNER JOIN
         (
            SELECT ASIN, MAX( isFiction ) AS isFiction, MAX( isNonFiction ) AS isNonFiction
            FROM tmp_table
            GROUP BY ASIN
            HAVING isFiction =1
            AND isNonFiction =1
         ) D
         WHERE D.ASIN=tmp_table.ASIN AND tmp_table.isNonFiction=1
```

In testing, this is getting the entire process down from about 90 seconds to 10 seconds.