# In a loop, some queries succeed, other queries fail 'No database selected'

Tags: php, mysql

I apply the same 2 queries to 3 tables, so just loop round and substitute the table names. The first INSERT query always works on test servers and on production. The second DELETE query works on two different test servers but is failing on production and throwing mysql error 1046 No database selected.

Affected code extract:

```
    $queries = array(
        "INSERT INTO knd_bkg.@table@
            SELECT DISTINCT SQL_NO_CACHE
            B.ASIN, Author, Title, EditorialReview, DetailPageURL, current_price, salesrank, number_reviews, erotica, G.BrowseNodeId, price_salesrank_checked_on
            FROM bkd_books.club_books B
            USE INDEX (free_quality)
            RIGHT JOIN bkd_books.book_genre G on G.ASIN=B.ASIN
            WHERE EXISTS
            (
              SELECT 1 FROM knd_bkg.genres K WHERE K.browsenode=G.BrowseNodeId
            )
            AND @priceWhere@
            AND price_salesrank_checked_on > '@newerThan@'
            AND B.number_reviews >= 4
            AND B.rating >= 4.0
            AND B.language = 'english'
            AND B.hide_knd=0
            AND B.public_domain=0;",
        "DELETE T FROM knd_bkg.@table@ T
         INNER JOIN
         (
             SELECT N.* FROM knd_bkg.@table@ N
             INNER JOIN
             (
                 SELECT DISTINCT ASIN, BrowseNodeId FROM knd_bkg.@table@
                 INNER JOIN knd_bkg.genres ON knd_bkg.genres.browsenode=knd_bkg.@table@.BrowseNodeId
                 WHERE isFiction=1
             ) F
             ON F.ASIN=N.ASIN
             INNER JOIN knd_bkg.genres
             ON knd_bkg.genres.browsenode=N.BrowseNodeId
             WHERE knd_bkg.genres.isNonFiction=1
         ) D
         USING (ASIN, BrowseNodeId)
         WHERE D.ASIN=T.ASIN AND D.BrowseNodeId=T.BrowseNodeId"
    );

    $tables = array(
        "free_books" => array('priceWhere' => "B.current_price = 0", 'timePeriod' => $freeTimePeriod),
        "99_books" => array('priceWhere' => "B.current_price > 0 AND B.current_price < 100", 'timePeriod' => $paidTimePeriod),
        "399_books" => array('priceWhere' => "B.current_price >= 100 AND B.current_price < 400", 'timePeriod' => $paidTimePeriod),
    );

    connectSlaveDB();

    foreach ($tables as $table => $data) {
        $newerThan = date("Y-m-d H:i:s", strtotime("-" . $data['timePeriod'] . " hours"));
        foreach ($queries as $query) {
            $query = str_replace('@table@', $table, $query);
            $query = str_replace('@newerThan@', $newerThan, $query);
            $query = str_replace('@priceWhere@', $data['priceWhere'], $query);
            Logger::_write(LOG_VERBOSE, "API - api/bkg/rebuild query: $query");
            $result = mysql_query($query);
            if (!$result) {
                Logger::_write(LOG_ERR, "API - api/bkg/rebuild FAILED: " . mysql_error());
                $success = false;
            } else {
                Logger::_write(LOG_VERBOSE, "API - api/bkg/rebuild SUCCESS");
            }
        }
    }
```

And connectSlaveDB()

```
function connectSlaveDB()
{
    global $dbSlave, $dbUser, $dbPass, $dbName;
    $connSlave = mysql_connect($dbSlave, $dbUser, $dbPass, TRUE);
    if (!$connSlave) {
        Logger::_write(LOG_CRIT, "Unable to connect to slave DB");
        include 'screens/error.inc.php';
        exit();
   }
    mysql_set_charset('utf8', $connSlave);
    mysql_select_db($dbName, $connSlave);
    return TRUE;
}
```

The tables are MEMORY tables, but I get the same error with MYISAM, and only on production. This query is running on a replication slave and does not involve the master, but previous code TRUNCATES the tables so I don't believe it is down to permissions. When the query is taken out of the log file, it works fine in phpMyAdmin. And it's fine on the test servers.

I don't get the reason for the 1046 No database selected error. And after 3 hours I might be missing something really obvious. Especially as the failure pattern is like this, for one DB connection:

```
INSERT on free_books - success
DELETE on free_books - fail
INSERT on 99_books - success
DELETE on 99_books - fail
INSERT on 399_books - success
DELETE on 399_books - fail
```

Please excuse ugly globals and deprecated mysql* functions. This is a legacy app that is rather out of date. I know...

Comment: are you closing your database after executing your query

Comment: try using the grave key (`) (the one with the tilde) in your queries

Comment: i would say give it a try with passing the connection resource as the second parameter to `mysql_query`

Comment: global mysql_* functions this is so bad use PDO or mysqli instead and don't use globals.

Comment: Sounds like you are deliberately running INSERTs on your slave. I hope this is not on a replicated database

Comment: @Anigel - yes I am, and no it's not replicated. Just creating a (mostly) RO table for a spurt of activity we want to keep away from the master.

Comment: @Robert - I agree and I already acknowledged this.

Comment: it could be that you have to many connections. An thus an error is thrown. Also, log the myqsl error instead of a useless 'unable to connect' error message. This will probably tell you more

Comment: @mukund - no, just when the final code for the whole visit has completed. This doesn't explain why the failure pattern which I've just updated to the question.

Comment: @Pinoniq - I do log mysql_error() at the point of failure as shown in the code. It's not the connection that is failing: it's the query. Nothing in mysql error logs to show any problem with connection limits though.

Comment: I haven't seen a delete specified like that before is the T correct? `DELETE T FROM`

Comment: @DevZer0 - I know swapping connections is ugly, but as all INSERTS correctly complete, and that mysql uses the last active connection, the connection seems okay. If the INSERT failed too, I would be thinking this too.

Comment: @Anigel - yeah, it's a bit convulted and that approach is used because the MEMORY table has no primary key, so I have to DELETE USING and this seemed to be the way to go. But as I say, it works fine on test servers and in phpMyAdmin so I think the query is good. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17442565/excluding-records-where-subquery-returns-results-that-need-to-be-mutually-exclus

Comment: @JohnKrommidas - worth a try, but made no difference

Comment: @Anigel - actually, you might be on to something. Though the query does work elsewhere, this is clearly catching others out so I shall fiddle with the query http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=23413

Comment: @Anigel - thanks for getting me on the right lines. I've posted a solution, but if you promote your comment to an answer, I'll accept it.

Comment: @markdwhite Glad you were able to get it sorted all the best

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The syntax of your DELETE query may be causing the problem

```
DELETE T FROM
```

I know this has caused issues with UPDATE queries sometimes before due to a mysql bug.

Re-writing your query to avoid the `T` reference should resolve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the T alias in the DELETE was causing problems, but I'm not quiet sure why. The problem is now fixed by making the DELETE query to be:

```
"DELETE knd_bkg.@table@ FROM knd_bkg.@table@
     INNER JOIN
     (
         SELECT N.* FROM knd_bkg.@table@ N
         INNER JOIN
         (
             SELECT DISTINCT ASIN, BrowseNodeId FROM knd_bkg.@table@
             INNER JOIN knd_bkg.genres ON knd_bkg.genres.browsenode=knd_bkg.@table@.BrowseNodeId
             WHERE isFiction=1
         ) F
         ON F.ASIN=N.ASIN
         INNER JOIN knd_bkg.genres
         ON knd_bkg.genres.browsenode=N.BrowseNodeId
         WHERE knd_bkg.genres.isNonFiction=1
     ) D
     USING (ASIN, BrowseNodeId)
     WHERE D.ASIN=knd_bkg.@table@.ASIN AND D.BrowseNodeId=knd_bkg.@table@.BrowseNodeId"
```

Comment: A much better query is now being used. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17442565/excluding-records-where-subquery-returns-results-that-need-to-be-mutually-exclus